# ARM GCC unaligned access

Tags: gcc, packed

if TStruct is packed, then this code ends with Str.D == 0x00223344 (not 0x11223344). Why? ARM GCC 4.7

```
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
   unsigned char B;
   unsigned int D;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) TStruct; 

volatile TStruct Str;

int main( void) {
  memset((void *)&Str, 0, sizeof(Str));
  Str.D = 0x11223344;
  if(Str.D != 0x11223344) {
     return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `__attribute__ ((packed))` packed seems to botch this code - so I'd say that is a bug in gcc - though the error is related to `Str` being volatile apparently.

Comment: If you force unaligned accesses on a given architecture then you had better understand how that architecture handles unaligned loads/stores.

Comment: @PaulR gcc will fix that up in cases such as this. It knows about alignment of the architecture, and generates code to do the proper bit operations when you annotate the struct with packed, such as this. (though it will not fix things up if you try to store/load such a struct from e.g. a char array). Apparently adding -fno-strict-volatile-bitfields will "fix" the OP's code, but it'll make the volatile qualifier of dubious usefulness

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem has nothing to do with unaligned access, but with structure definition. `int` is not necessarily 32 bit long.  According to the C standard, int is at least 16 bit long, and char is at least 8 bits long.

My guess is, Your compiler optimizes TStruct so it looks like this:

```
struct {
   unsigned char B : 8;
   unsigned int D : 24;
} ...;
```

When you are assigning `0x11223344` to `Str.D`, than according to the C standard, the compiler must only make sure that at least 16 bits (`0x3344`) are written to `Str.D`. You didn't specify that `Str.D` is 32 bit long, only that it is at least 16 bits long.

Your compiler may also arrange the struct like this:

```
struct {
   unsigned char B : 16;
   unsigned int D : 16;
} ...;
```

`B` is at least 8 bits long, and `D` is at least 16 bits long, all ok.

Probably, what you want to do, is:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
   uint8_t B;
   uint32_t D;
} __attribute__((packed)) TStruct;
```

That way You can ensure a 32-bit value `0x11223344` properly writes to `Str.D`. It is a good idea to use size constrained types for __packed structs.
As for unaligned access of a member inside a struct, the compiler should take care of it. If a compiler knows the structure definition, then when you are accessing `Str.D` it should take care of any unaligned access and bit/byte operations.